# Is it possible in Perforce to add a missing integrate record?

Tags: integration, perforce

Recently I submitted a file to Perforce as “add” (a new file).

Then I submitted several more changes to it.

Now I realize that the original “add” should have been an “integrate” because the file is really a copy and modification of another, existing file.

Is there a way to add the integration link after the fact?

If not, what is the easiest way of doing this? If we obliterate all the affected changelists, and then re-submit them but with the correct integration history, will that work?

Comment: Sometimes doing a baseless merge -  `integrate -i` - helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just talked to Perforce Support on the phone. The answer is no, you cannot “change history”. However, the recommended course of action is to:

- Take a copy of each change made to the new file(s)
- Obliterate all the added files that should have been an *integrate*
- Re-submit each change that was made

Comment: As evil otto said I'd expect that baseless merge results in a similar history. What you want is that you can integrate back and forth (i.e. have a relationship between 2 files). You can achieve that by integrating/merging the actual file that you wanted to be the integration source in the beginning on top of your current (new) file.

Comment: Barring a strict policy or technical need to have the history just right, I'd edit the first commit's description to indicate it should have been an integration, and from where, then go the baseless merge route to fix future merge issues.

Comment: With the baseless merge idea, `p4 annotate` will produce wrong results. (Also, I’m amazed how you all seem to know better than Perforce Support?...)

Comment: It's a matter of effort. Yes, you can get it just right, but is that important enough to bring things to a halt while you go through the process? In a decade of admining Perforce I saw a lot of time and money wasted on such things with no benefit even anticipated. That is, the person insisting on it could not come up with a plausible use case for why it would be important. Indeed, I can't remember a case where it actually mattered - after the problem was buried under a dozen or a hundred revisions, no one at all ever saw it again. As I said above, have a good reason before you jump.

Comment: @William: You sound like one of those managers who rejects the developers’ reasoning just because *you* don’t understand the benefit. You have no idea that no-one ever saw it again: you only know that no-one told you, and given your attitude, that doesn’t at all surprise me! — We fixed our issue using the method recommended by Perforce Support and we brought nothing “to a halt”.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got that from what I wrote. (It was usually managers who couldn't come up with any reasoning :-)

Comment: @William: Got what? I said you *sound like* X, and I said that you *cannot know* Y. I didn’t imply that you are a manager, but I criticise the attitude that just because they cannot communicate the reasoning *to you*, you think there isn’t any and the change is unnecessary and you know better than the people who are actually affected. Of course I’m exaggerating, but only to highlight the issue.

Comment: You ignored my comments about policies, technical needs, and use cases which would make the canonical solution worthwhile. Balancing that is what happens if you obliterate a branch (even a one-file branch) developers have already synced and are possibly editing. If you're in a small shop, that's less of a problem, but it can be serious when there are 5,000 users, around the world, some almost 12 hours away (my situation). So, yes, I'd expect them to to communicate their reasoning to me because I'd likely have to justify it later (if not seek permission first).

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to generate Perforce journal (database) records that put the missing data in place.  These are plain text entries that are replayed into the live database by a system admin.  The database schema is documented: www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/schema

You'd need to be very careful and work with Perforce Support while doing this, and try it on a test system first.  It's normally not worth the effort.